# XML file import to SQL database with multiple children

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, bulk-load

I'm trying to import an XML file into a SQL Server database. Please have a look on the code and on the xml file. Thanks in advance.

I tried to google lot of pages but all of them deal with only one child (or how to call it).

But In my real xml the structure is like

```
:1x supplier --> multiple orders --> multiple customers --> multiple products.
```

We need to create a stored procedure which will be called when we get the XML file.

Thanks again Petr

SQL code:

```
DROP TABLE #TEST

CREATE TABLE #TEST
(CUSTID VARCHAR(10),CUSTNAME VARCHAR(50),PRODUCT VARCHAR(500))

INSERT INTO #TEST(CUSTID,CUSTNAME,PRODUCT)
SELECT
    x.orders.query('order/customer/cust_id').value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
    x.orders.query('order/customer/name').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
    x.orders.query('order/product_lines/product/supplier_prod_num').
   value('.','VARCHAR(500)') 
FROM
   (SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
    FROM OPENROWSET(
          BULK '\\test\Test.xml',
          SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)) AS T(x) 
    CROSS APPLY
        x.nodes('order_batch/orders/order/product_lines/product') AS x(orders)

select * from #test
```

XML file to test:

```
<order_batch>
  <order_header>
    <doc_format_ver>1.0</doc_format_ver>
    <originating_software>
      <software_name>test</software_name>
      <software_ver>2.0</software_ver>
    </originating_software>
  </order_header>
  <supplier>
    <cp_supplier_id>93</cp_supplier_id>
    <name>supname</name>
    <address_line_1>address_line_1</address_line_1>
    <address_line_2>address_line_1</address_line_2>
  </supplier>
  <orders>
    <order o_count="1">
      <customer>
        <cust_id>7240</cust_id>
        <name>CustNamek</name>
        <address_line_1>address_line_1</address_line_1>
        <address_line_2>address_line_1</address_line_2>
      </customer>
      <order_details>
        <date_created>2012-10-08</date_created>
        <time_created>05:37:11</time_created>
      </order_details>
      <product_lines>
        <product p_count="1">
          <supplier_prod_num>15115</supplier_prod_num>
          <qty_type>E</qty_type>
        </product>
        <product p_count="2">
          <supplier_prod_num>010211</supplier_prod_num>
          <qty_type>E</qty_type>
        </product>
      </product_lines>
    </order>
    <order o_count="2">
      <customer>
        <cust_id>7238</cust_id>
        <name>custname</name>
        <address_line_1>address_line_1</address_line_1>
        <address_line_2>address_line_1</address_line_2>
      </customer>
      <order_details>
        <supplier_ref>0093513982</supplier_ref>
        <delivery_date>2012-10-08</delivery_date>
        <special_instructions />
      </order_details>
      <product_lines>
        <product p_count="1">
          <supplier_prod_num>6748</supplier_prod_num>
          <qty_type>E</qty_type>
        </product>
        <product p_count="2">
          <supplier_prod_num>6744</supplier_prod_num>
          <qty_type>E</qty_type>
        </product>
      </product_lines>
    </order>
  </orders>
</order_batch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (CUSTID VARCHAR(50), CUSTNAME VARCHAR(50), PRODUCT VARCHAR(500))

DECLARE @input XML 

SELECT @input = CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET
     (BULK '\\test\Test.xml',
      SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(X)

INSERT INTO #TEST(CUSTID, CUSTNAME, PRODUCT)
    SELECT
        Customers.value('(cust_id)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        Customers.value('(name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
        Products.value('(supplier_prod_num)[1]', 'VARCHAR(500)')
    FROM
        @input.nodes('/order_batch/orders/order') AS Tbl(Orders)
    CROSS APPLY
        Orders.nodes('customer') AS TblC(Customers)
    CROSS APPLY
        Orders.nodes('product_lines/product') AS TblP(Products)
```

This "shreds" the XML and uses nested `CROSS APPLY .nodes()` methods to extract any number of customers from the order node, and any number of products, too.

Comment: Hi Marc, It works better than before. It show all customers which is good but then it will show always just first product from each customer. Even if there is multiple amount. Thanks again.